# Framemaker 2017 and change bars

Tags: technical-writing, software, tools

I have a document that is +2k and it’s all tables. I use change bars to track changes.
Q – Does FM note what changed when it assigns a change bar? Do I always have to use 'Track Changes'? In Word, it will have a comment when a change has happened.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use a particular piece of software. The online community forums and help documents are the place to find the answer to this question.

Comment: I disagree about it being off topic. There are dozens if not hundreds of Scrivener questions here. FrameMaker questions are equally on topic. But I do agree this may not be the best forum, given that there are forums dedicated to FrameMaker.

Comment: you might try Graphic Design SE; that seems to be all software related now.

Comment: Framemaker is a specialist tool used by technical writers; it's not like MS Word or Notepad.  This is on-topic here, same as the Scrivener questions.

Comment: Agreed that this is on-topic, but feel free to pop over to the [meta thread on this](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/276/26) and comment/vote.

Comment: I had no idea there was a Framemaker forum. I've always post my FM questions on Super User.  Thanks, I'll repost on Framemaker forum.

Comment: @LindaLawson-Bruton as far as I know, Framemaker questions are also welcome on Super User.  With 160+ Stack Exchange sites, there are bound to be overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

Change bars do not keep a record of what has changed, it's just a visual indication of "something has changed in this line of text".

You'll have to use Track Changes if you want to keep records.